# Ant task for generating XSD from POJOs

Tags: ant, xsd, pojo

Is there an ant task for generating an XSD from POJOs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that you want to serialize a Java POJO object and then use XSD to validate the serialised XML data, or author new object instances which can instantiated via your de-serialization process.

Thing is Java XML serialization comes in two favours (Examples follow):

- [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) XML is dynamically generated from fixed object class description
- [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) Java classes dynamically generated from fixed XML Schema

Now perhaps you're using something else that combines both approaches?

What I'd recommend is create (or generate) an XSD based on the XML your object creates when serialized. Relatively speaking Java objects don't change that often and when they do a far great challenge is supporting multiple versions (Reading data encoded for the older version of your object). To address this challenge I'd recommend reading the following article for one possible solution:

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/migrate-serialized-java